# How to create an array from calculations of another array excel vba

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am new to coding and trying to learn through VBA. What I am trying to do is calculate outliers in a data set following a procedure. My trouble is trying to identify the elements in the Data Set that are furthest from the mean (the outlier) and looping that k times. Most of the code is very messy as I have been trying to find out what is wrong so ignore the MsgBox's and ugly formatting. In the last part of my code I tried taking the elements from DataSet and subtracting them from the mean and storing those values in a new array. After that I would take absolute value of the elements in the Diff array and store them in a new array (Diff2). I know I could bypass Diff2 by just taking the absolute value of the calculation of Diff. When I run the code I get the type mismatch error and after some investigation i realized that Diff (and Diff2) are not arrays. If anyone knows of how I can make Diff an array or of a better workaround for this that would be much appreciated!

```
Sub CalculateOutliers()
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim mean As Double
    Dim SD As Double
    Dim X As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim DataSet As Variant
    Dim ESDPrin As Double

    DataSet = Selection.Value
    'Copies highlighted data into DataSet variable
    'Cell A1 is (1,1) Because it starts at 0 which is out of range

    n = Selection.CountLarge
    'Counts number of entries
    'If n < 20 Then
        'MsgBox "Data set too small"
        'Exit Sub
    'End If
    'Ends Subroutine if data set is too small for this analysis

    If n < 50 Then
        k = Int(n / 10)
    Else
        k = 5
    End If
    'determines k = number of possible outliers

    mean = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(DataSet)
    'Calculates mean of Data Set
    MsgBox mean & "Average"

    SD = Application.WorksheetFunction.StDev(DataSet)
    'Calculates Standard Deviation of Data Set

    Dim element As Variant
    Dim Diff As Variant

    For Each element In DataSet
        Diff = element - mean
        MsgBox Diff & " Difference"
    Next element

    Dim P As Integer
    Dim Outlier As Integer
    Dim Diff2 As Variant

    Diff2 = Abs(Diff)

    For P = 1 To k
        Outlier = UBound(Diff, 1)
        MsgBox Outlier
   Next P
End Sub
```

Comment: If you want them as an array, you need to define the size of the array desired, e.g. Dim Diff(1 to 2) as Variant, or use the ReDim Preserve command to expand your array (in one axis only) without losing your previous entries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here how you create the Diff Array with size n

```
ReDim Diff(1 To n) As Double
Dim i As Long
For Each element In DataSet
    i = i + 1
    Diff(i) = element - mean
Next element
```

However, I don't think that this is the correct way to go. There's no need for a `Diff` array. What you should do is, once you have calculated the `mean` and `SD`, iterate on the `DataSet` array itself, check for each element its absolute difference with mean, divide by stdev, and compare this ratio to some threshold (say 2 or 3) to decide whether this element is an outlier, in which case you print it out as an outlier. Something like this:

```
For Each element In DataSet
   If abs(element - mean) / SD > 3 Then Debug.Print "outlier: " & element
Next element
```

Comment: I agree with the alternative way but thank you for answering both questions so I can know for future reference! This helps me out a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think code would be like this

```
Sub CalculateOutliers()
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim mean As Double
    Dim SD As Double
    Dim X As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim DataSet As Variant
    Dim ESDPrin As Double

    DataSet = Selection.Value
    'Copies highlighted data into DataSet variable
    'Cell A1 is (1,1) Because it starts at 0 which is out of range

    n = Selection.CountLarge
    'Counts number of entries
    'If n < 20 Then
        'MsgBox "Data set too small"
        'Exit Sub
    'End If
    'Ends Subroutine if data set is too small for this analysis

    If n < 50 Then
        k = Int(n / 10)
    Else
        k = 5
    End If
    'determines k = number of possible outliers

    mean = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(DataSet)
    'Calculates mean of Data Set
    MsgBox mean & "Average"

    SD = Application.WorksheetFunction.StDev(DataSet)
    'Calculates Standard Deviation of Data Set

    Dim element As Variant
    Dim Diff() As Variant, Diff2() As Variant, j As Integer

    For Each element In DataSet
        j = j + 1
        ReDim Preserve Diff(1 To j): ReDim Preserve Diff2(1 To j)
        Diff(j) = element - mean
        Diff2(j) = Abs(Diff(j))
        MsgBox Diff(j) & " Difference"
        MsgBox Diff2(j) & " Difference abs "
    Next element
    MsgBox UBound(Diff)
    'Dim P As Integer
    'Dim Outlier As Integer
    'Dim Diff2 As Variant

End Sub
```